# Python lxml - find parent of comment

Tags: python, get, comments, lxml, parent

I need to find certain text from within a comment and then get the parent of that comment. here's the xml:

```
<video>
    <read_only_info>
        <read_only_value key="content-review-status">Live-Reviewed</read_only_value>
    </read_only_info>
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <assets>
        <asset type="full">
            <!—A place for some text—>
            <data_file role="source">
                <size>121190418069</size>
            </data_file>
        </asset>
        <asset type="preview">
            <!--A place for some text—>
```

So I need to find the text in the comment with "A Place for some text" then I need to get the parent of that comment, "full" or "preview".

I can find the comment with that text:

```
comments = tree.xpath('//comment()')
for c in comments:
    p = c.getparent()[0]
    print c.text
```

But don't know how to then get the parent of that text, "full" or "preview".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c.getparent()` returns the parent element (the asset tag)

```
>>> c.getparent()
<Element asset at 0x103535d88>
```

You can then call `.attrib` on that to access the attributes

```
>>> c.getparent().attrib
{'type': 'full'}
>>> c.getparent().attrib['type']
'full'
```